# Axis in tf.linalg.normalize

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to normalize my tensor with rows as samples and columns as features.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/normalize

If I use axis=1, I get error message. If I used axis=0, the output looks fine.
But how to decide axis?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the general rule applied for axis

```
axis=0: Apply operation column-wise, across all rows for each column.
axis=1: Apply operation row-wise, across all columns for each row.
```